# Why is an unrelated section of my Bootstrap site not rendering properly after adding a HTML5 video header?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I have been customising [this existing Bootstrap based website template](http://www.templategarden.com/preview/tempo/template/index.html) to create my own website.

I have changed the header to have a full width video background instead of a static image using the following HTML and CSS:

```
<!------------- Background Video ----------------->
<div class = "video-container">
  <video preload = "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop= "loop" volume = "0" poster = "bokeh.jpg">
   <source src = "video/bokeh.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
   <source src = "video/bokeh.webm" type = "video/webm">
  </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.video-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
video{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.78;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

After adding this video, a section of the website near the bottom of the page **What Our Clients Say** does not render properly. I am sure it's a browser rendering issue because it renders differently each time you reload or scroll the page, various chunks of white space.

Here are two screenshots to show you the kind of rendering problem I'm having - this is on two separate reloads:

[image: Rendering example]
[image: Rendering example 2]

I have tried reducing the resolution of the video down to 360p but this has not helped. As soon as I remove the video, the rendering issue goes away.

Any ideas?!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `z-index`?

Comment: Its a good idea to share a link to the online version or summarized version of markup and CSS to let people reproduce the problem

Comment: Aaaaaagh @SaucedApples - yes, that worked! FFS, I am so rubbish at CSS... Trying to improve, but Google doesn't have the answer to everything! I think I might have added the z-index in desperation to get the video working at an earlier stage (had CSS problems then too...) and never removed it when it turned out something else was the problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Trix - Thanks for the feedback, will try and improve any future questions.

Comment: @Bekahland Good, I've posted it as an answer, please up vote and select as answer if that worked.  I would be grateful.  Keep practising as you are and it will soon come to you!

Comment: Great, have done so. You never know when someone else might be Googling for answers one day and find your answer useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing the z-index:

```
.video-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}
video{
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.78;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp